# Why does qemu-system-arm hang if dtb and machine are swapped?

Tags: raspberry-pi, qemu, arm

I am trying to use qemu-system-arm to emulate an embedded system.  I am using Ubuntu 20.04 and installed the backport of QEMU emulator version 5.0.0 (Debian 1:5.0-5ubuntu6~ppa0).  I thought I would try something "simple" to start, and emulate a Raspberry Pi.  After trying about a dozen examples, I finally found one which works [here](https://lynxbee.com/emulate-raspberrypi-2-on-ubuntu-20-04-using-qemu/#.YiiaMHXMLx0).
Following the instructions from the link to extract the kernel and dtb, I am then able to emulate a Raspberry Pi 2b with the command

```
qemu-system-arm -M raspi2 -kernel ./kernel7.img -dtb ./bcm2709-rpi-2-b.dtb -sd ./2020-02-13-raspbian-buster-lite.img -serial stdio -append "$(<cmdline.txt)"
```

This is great.  However, if I try to change it to run a different revision of raspberry pi, qemu hangs.

```
qemu-system-arm -M versatilepb -cpu arm1176 -m 256 -kernel ./kernel7.img -dtb ./bcm2709-rpi-2-b.dtb -sd ./2020-02-13-raspbian-buster-lite.img -serial stdio -append "$(<cmdline.txt)"
qemu-system-arm -M versatilepb -cpu arm1176 -m 256 -kernel ./kernel7.img -dtb ./bcm2708-rpi-b.dtb -sd ./2020-02-13-raspbian-buster-lite.img -serial stdio -append "$(<cmdline.txt)"
```

I believe that `-M versatilepb -cpu arm1176 -m 256` is an approximation of the Raspberry Pi 1 architecture.  I tried it with both the dtb for a Raspberry Pi 2 and Raspberry Pi 1, but it fails to start with VM with complaints:

```
pulseaudio: set_sink_input_volume() failed
pulseaudio: Reason: Invalid argument
pulseaudio: set_sink_input_mute() failed
pulseaudio: Reason: Invalid argument
```

I also tried:

```
qemu-system-aarch64 -M raspi3 -kernel ./kernel7.img -dtb ./bcm2710-rpi-3-b.dtb -sd ./2020-02-13-raspbian-buster-lite.img -serial stdio -append "$(<cmdline.txt)"
```

Which I believe should emulate a Raspberry Pi 3, but it hangs without printing any output at all.  I have also tried a whole host of other combinations, most of which hang without printing any output.

I am hoping for some kind of explanation about what causes qemu to hang without any output to the terminal (and with a blank Qemu window).  Is this caused by a mismatch between the machine loaded by -M and the dtb file and/or kernel?  What specifically does not match?  Is it the memory addresses used?  The available peripherals?

Or is this just normal behavior for qemu-system-arm - that it only works with a limited set of hardware, and that anything else requires detailed knowledge of the hardware architecture in order to precisely configure a matching VM?

Or is it possible there is something wrong with my qemu installation.  As stated above, I about a dozen examples (such as [this](https://azeria-labs.com/emulate-raspberry-pi-with-qemu/) and [this](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/117234/how-to-emulate-raspberry-pi-in-qemu)) that did not work for me.  I assume this is because the examples were for a different version of qemu and/or I was doing something subtly wrong, but maybe not?